# Find all real values a of the system

Tags: systems-of-equations, cubics, symmetric-polynomials

Find all the actual values that can assume it so that the system

$\begin{cases}
x^3 + y^2 + z^2 = a \\
x^2 + y^3 + z^2 = a \\
x^2+ y^2 + z^3 = a
\end{cases}$

has solution with x, y, z distinct real two by two.

What I thought: Comparing the equations we get $x^2(x-1)=y^2(y-1)=z^2(z-1)=K$ for some $K$.Now let $P(t)=t^2-t-K$.Clearly $x,y,z$ are the roots of this equation so $x+y+z=0,xy+yz+zx=-1$

But how to continue? I don't know how to equate these equations

Comment: What means "distinct real two by two"?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I suppse "pairwise distinct reals"?

Comment: I think they are a couple of distinct real values that satisfy the equation

Comment: The solution looks terrible.

Comment: Now compute $x^2+y^2+z^2$ and $x^3+y^3+z^3.$

Comment: What's the graph of $f(x)=x^3-x^2$ look like?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By considering the termwise differences between two equations we have $x^3-x^2=y^3-y^2=z^3-z^2=K$, so $x,y,z$ are the roots of $p(t)=t^3-t^2-K$. This polynomial has three distinct roots iff its discriminant is positive, i.e. iff $K\in\left(-\frac{4}{27},0\right)$. By Viète's formulas we have $x+y+z=1$ and $xy+xz+yz=0$, so $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$. Since
$$ x^3 = x^2+K, \qquad y^3=y^2+K,\qquad z^3=z^2+K $$
we have $x^3+y^3+z^3 = (x^2+y^2+z^2)+3K = 1+3K$ and 
$$ 3a = (x^3+y^3+z^3)+2(x^2+y^2+z^2) = 3K+3.$$
$a=K+1$ gives $\color{red}{a\in\left(\frac{23}{27},1\right)}$. It is not difficult to check that this is also a sufficient condition for the system to have distinct solutions.

Comment: Ah, it seems the OP got $x+y+z$ and $xy++xz+yz$ messed up

Comment: I arrived where everyone is between 1 and -1/3. Am I right?

Comment: I got a different result than above?
Consider $f(t)=t^3-t^2+x^2+y^2+z^2-a=0$ which has roots at $x,y,z$. Then, $x+y+z=1,xy+yz+zx=0,xyz=a-(x^2+y^2+z^2)$.

$x^2+y^2+z^2=(x+y+z)^2-2(xy+yz+zx)=1$
$x^2+y^2+z^2=1\implies -1\leq x,y,z \leq 1$
So, $-1\leq a-1=xyz \leq1\implies \boxed{0\leq a \leq 2}$

Comment: @EsposaDoYoongi: yours is a necessary condition, but not a sufficient one: you are not imposing that $x,y,z$ are distinct anywhere.